# Where to store tns, username and password for a oracle DB connection in Unix to use with Python and R

Tags: python, r, linux, oracle, passwords

i'm quite new to use unix and i'm stuck with this problem.
I have a linux machine with R/RStudio and Python/Anaconda installed.
I have given this machine access to hostname, port and service of my DB.

Now i have to create some sort of configuration file where i can store the username and password of the schema i want this machine to use to get access to db and query it through python or R.

This configuration file must secure the password so noone will know it outside the creator of the config file, other users will use r and python to connect to db via some library usinfg the credentials in this config file.

How can i achieve this? Sorry if i have sayd something wrong.
If you know some other methods to achieve this kind of security level please explain

Comment: Each user should save their respective passwords in `~/.profile` file with appropriate permissions (e.g. 600). Then access system variables in R using `Sys.getenv('HOME')` and in python `import os; print(os.environ['HOME'])`

Comment: thanks, the db schema (user) i have to use is only one so every users will have in their respective .profile the same credentials ? there is no way to centralize it and make this centralized config readable by all but modifiable by only one so-called admin ?

Comment: sure you could make one central file and set the permission to 740 so only one user has the full permissions and everyone else in the group has only read, but then everyone can read everyone else's passwords

Comment: the credential is only one <DB_USER; DB_PWD> equal for all users that can access through this machine ... there is no way to do a unique file containing those information as administrator and give reading access to all normal users so they can connect to db using this config but without let everyone see username and password ? some sort of encryption ?

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Either the user can read the credential file or they can't. As Nullman and abhiieor have suggested you should have separate credentials for each user in order to protect them from one another. Perhaps if you trust the users enough to use the credentials you should also trust them enough to see the credentials? Then your solution is to make the credential file 740 as Nullman suggested.

Comment: ok so let's opt for the centralized 740 file, how can i achieve this? i'm totally newbie on this